# All pages are blank when going to a site from the picker

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Behold a sad image:

[image]

Steps:

1. Pick a site to visit from the sidebar search picker thing - not the sites pinned in your sidebar
2. See a blank questions page
3. Tap around the other tabs and see that they are also blank
4. Tap the ask question button and cancel out of the subsequent screen
5. Content has returned to the pages! Huzzah!

Beta version 1.1.0.108, iPhone only, iOS 7.1.2.

Comment: Image confirmed for sad

Comment: Even sadder, there is no way to go back, no site switcher, nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

We updated the menu controller (MMDrawerController) a few days ago, which included [this change](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController/commit/86cf110698575a5a885b587e1db23e5cd2edd3b3#diff-baf5b481ab5dcdad1936b002c4795d01R430) that eliminated instantaneous and erroneous `viewWillAppear:/viewDidAppear:` messages to offscreen views (they aren't going to appear since they're offscreen).  The expectation is that the code will get `viewWillAppear:` when the view controller is transitioned back onto the screen.

Unfortunately our code looks like:

```
[self hideTheSiteListAnimated:YES];
[self goToTheNewSite];
```

The problem is that hiding the site list triggers a transition to start (`viewWillAppear:` gets called on everything but our new site controller) but doesn't immediately add the views back to the window (meaning `goToTheNewSite` doesn't `viewWillAppear:` either).  When the transition completes, iOS sees that the view controller finished transitioning but never started, spits out an error to the console and lets the app continue in an invalid state.

The new code looks like this:

```
[self goToTheNewSite];
[self hideTheSiteListAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: ~15 hour turnaround for the fix. Nice work :)